# gitignore not working even after usual correction

Tags: eclipse, git

I have the common problem of gitignore not ignoring files. Since the files were tracked (and committed) prior to adding them to gitignore I have tried the usual:

git rm -r --cached .

git add .

git commit -m "whatever"

While I have a clean directory after, as soon as I do another Java compile (which updates */bin/* as in gitignore) the files in bin are shown as unstaged. How do I troubleshoot this? TIA.

Comment: You keep referring to the file as `gitignore` - is that just a style of writing, or is that the actual file name? Because if it is, that's your problem - it should be `.gitignore`.

Comment: Style. I know the actual name is .gitignore.

Comment: Just making sure :-) Can you share the contents of your gitignore file?

Comment: */bin/*
*/.git/*
*/.settings/*
*/.classpath
*/.project

Comment: It occurs to me that I may have the .gitignore file at the wrong directory level. I'm using Eclipse and it may have set it up wrong. It should go at the same level as the .git directory, right?

Comment: Can you edit this info into the question and format it correctly? It's quite hard to read from the comments. WRT the file's location - yes, that's fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have restore Eclipse back to normal and now .gitignore is in the same directory as .git. However, I am back to the orignal problem. Here is my .gitignore:

```
*/bin/*
*/.git/*
*/.settings/*
*/.classpath
*/.project
```

git status shows the following:

```
On branch master
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   bin/StokerMonitor/Configuration.class
        modified:   bin/StokerMonitor/GUI$2.class
        modified:   bin/StokerMonitor/GUI.class

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Comment: You should not use answers to add details on your own question, either edit your question, or add a comment on the question. When you have done it, please remove the answer.

Comment: Sorry but I cannot (or do not know how to) get comments to properly format structured text like answers do. Indenting and new line characters seem to be ignored.

Comment: If you need to provide properly formatted structured text, you should edit the question. Question provide the same formatting as answers, so there should be no reason to use answer beside actually answering the question.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know that was acceptable. I thought the original question should be left alone. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to matter as I'm not getting any help on this anyway.

Comment: It is totally acceptable, it is even recommended. The history is always available in case one wants to access the first version. You can read [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21788/how-does-editing-work) for more information. Maybe if you "cleanup" your question/answer properly, people will answer it.

Answer (score 0):

Check your `.gitignore` file is using `UTF-8` character encoding (or `US-ASCII`).

I had this today, even on a new git repo, git was ignoring the `.gitignore` file and including the files in `git status` output.  After wasting a good 1/2 hour or so trawling the net I resorted to copying a `.gitignore` from elsewhere over the top and edited it and git started ignoring the files.

I noticed afterwards that my editor now said it was `UTF-8`.  I also had a `.npmrc` file that was not working as expected, turned out to be the same issue, it was `UTF-16 LE` rather than `UTF-8` encoded.